# (Qt) Qtimer doesn't work. What details have I missed?

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a header xx.h, there are two classes, one is a Qt class *"QClass"* and another is a generic class *"Normal"*. And declare an external *Normal* variable. *Normal* has a *QClass* member.
Here is the content of xx.h :

```
#ifndef XX_H
#define XX_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class QClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QClass();
    ~QClass();

private:
    QTimer *t;
private slots:
    void func();
};

class Normal
{
    int i;

    QClass q;
};

extern Normal globalN;

#endif
```

I also wrote a xx.cpp to implement xx.h

```
#include "xx.h"

QClass::QClass() : t(new QTimer)
{
    connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(func()));
    t->start(1000);
}

QClass::~QClass()
{
    delete t;
}


void QClass::func()
{
    static int n = 0;
    ++n;
}
```

And here is my main.cpp, here I define globalN. The class *Why* is my Qt window class, it is declared in *why.h*. This header is not important, so I didn't post its content.

```
#include "why.h"
#include "xx.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

Normal globalN;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Why w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My idea is that I put globalN in global scope, so when program starts, it constructs globalN, then the timer start to tick.
  In order to check these stuff work right or not, I set a breakpoint in  `QClass::func()`, to check if QTimer calls `func()`, but it doesn't.
  I examine the code a long time, but I can't find where I mistake, please tell me. Thank you!!

Comment: class `Normal` has a `QClass` member q. `globalN` isn't really used, I just hope its constructor will start QTimer for me.

Comment: QTimer relies on the event loop in QApplication. When you initialize it in global static variable there is no QApplication and event loop yet. Try to add a method initTimer() in QClass and promote it via Normal. Then use dynamic QTimer created with new. Create it in initTimer() method after QApplication is intstantiated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your timer to start, you need an event loop. To have an event loop you need to have an active `QApplication`.

Here, since `globalN` is global, it is created before your `QApplication`, so your timer is not started.

Comment: Having that event loop running is one of the crucial elements needed in order to make QTimer work properly. Missing that event loop will make a QTimer dysfunctional